# Python set Operation strange behaviour

Tags: python, set

I have below code snippet

```
seta = ["apple","orange","grapes","mango", "starfruit"]
setb = ["papaya","mango","jackfruit","grapes","lychee"]

def setOperation(seta, setb):
    union = set(seta) | set(setb)
    print(list(union)) 
    intersection = set(seta) & set(setb)
    print(list(intersection))
    difference = set(seta) - set(setb)
    print(list(difference))
    difference = set(setb) - set(seta)
    print(list(difference))
    sdifference = set(seta) ^ set(setb)
    print(list(sdifference))
    print(list(frozenset(set(seta))))
    
setOperation(seta,setb)
```

which produces different different output everytime I run it.
Like -

```
['jackfruit', 'apple', 'mango', 'starfruit', 'grapes', 'lychee', 'orange', 'papaya']                                          
['grapes', 'mango']                                                                                                           
['orange', 'apple', 'starfruit']                                                                                              
['jackfruit', 'papaya', 'lychee']                                                                                             
['jackfruit', 'apple', 'starfruit', 'lychee', 'papaya', 'orange']                                                             
['orange', 'apple', 'grapes', 'mango', 'starfruit']
```

and

```
['grapes', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange', 'starfruit', 'lychee', 'papaya', 'jackfruit']                                          
['grapes', 'mango']                                                                                                           
['starfruit', 'apple', 'orange']                                                                                              
['lychee', 'papaya', 'jackfruit']                                                                                             
['apple', 'orange', 'starfruit', 'lychee', 'papaya', 'jackfruit']                                                             
['grapes', 'starfruit', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange']
```

but I want the output as below -

```
['apple', 'grapes', 'jackfruit', 'lychee', 'mango', 'orange', 'papaya', 'starfruit']
['grapes', 'mango']
['apple', 'orange', 'starfruit']
['jackfruit', 'lychee', 'papaya']
['apple', 'jackfruit', 'lychee', 'orange', 'papaya', 'starfruit']
```

Due to this change of order I am failing one code competition exam again.
Please do let me know if I missed something simple or did anything stupid. I want the output in lexicographical order.
TIA

Comment: The thing you are missing is that `set`s in python are unordered. So you can't assume they will maintain order.

Comment: @bali what? What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets are unordered so you can't expect to get a consistent order. Since your expected output is in sorted order, you can simply view the sorted union/intersection etc like so:

```
seta = set(["apple","orange","grapes","mango", "starfruit"])
setb = set(["papaya","mango","jackfruit","grapes","lychee"])

print(sorted(seta | setb)) # Union
print(sorted(seta & setb)) # Intersection
# ... etc ...
```

Comment: I tried this but still not clearing the exam, one thing I for to mention, they are expecting one line at the end of my ouput "Returned value is a frozenset".
I tried printing this string as print("Returned value is a frozenset") but still not clearing the exam. help plz

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1):

Set is an unordered data structure in Python. Given that you want the output in lexicographical order, just add 'sorted()' inside print commands:

```
seta = ["apple","orange","grapes","mango", "starfruit"]
setb = ["papaya","mango","jackfruit","grapes","lychee"]

def setOperation(seta, setb):
    union = set(seta) | set(setb)
    print(sorted(union)) 
    intersection = set(seta) & set(setb)
    print(sorted(intersection))
    difference = set(seta) - set(setb)
    print(sorted(difference))
    difference = set(setb) - set(seta)
    print(sorted(difference))
    sdifference = set(seta) ^ set(setb)
    print(sorted(sdifference))
    print(sorted(frozenset(set(seta))))
    
setOperation(seta,setb)
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'grapes', 'jackfruit', 'lychee', 'mango', 'orange', 'papaya', 'starfruit']
['grapes', 'mango']
['apple', 'orange', 'starfruit']
['jackfruit', 'lychee', 'papaya']
['apple', 'jackfruit', 'lychee', 'orange', 'papaya', 'starfruit']
['apple', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange', 'starfruit']
```

Comment: Btw you can use `sorted(x)` instead of `sorted(list(x))` since `sorted` returns a sorted `list` of any iterable (`set`s are iterable).